# Why does tikz report that my dimensions are too large?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I'm trying to create a figure using Tikz, but it gives me the "Dimensions too large error". I suspect it's because I'm trying to chart functions that approach 0 and 1 in the limits, and Tikz can't exactly handle this. Any tips on how I can get the Tikz to work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1},height=6cm,width=6cm,xmin=0.5,ymin=0.5,ymax=1,xmax=1,samples=500,ytick={0.5,1},xtick={0.5,1}, xlabel={$v_1$},
    axis lines=left]
        \nextgroupplot[title={}, ylabel={$x_1$}]
              \addplot[blue,]{min(1,(\x/(2*(1-min(1,\x)))))};\label{plots:plot1};   

              \addplot[black] {((3*\x-1)/(2*\x))};\label{plots:plot2};
                \addplot[black, dashed] {(\x)};\label{plots:plot3};
         \nextgroupplot[title={}, ylabel={$x_2$}]
              \addplot[blue]{(max((2-3*\x)/(2-2*\x),0))};\label{plots:plot1};        \addplot[black] {(1-\x)/(2*\x)};\label{plots:plot2};
                \addplot[black, dashed] {(1-\x)};\label{plots:plot3};
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- 
          node[anchor=south,rotate=90] { } 
          (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.south)--
      coordinate(legendpos) 
      (bot|-current bounding box.south);
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ]at([yshift=-1ex, xshift=-17ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plots:plot1}& F(x)&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot2}& G(x)&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot3}& H(x)& \\};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post the `MWE` as compilable format, i.e., from `\documentclass{...}...`  to `\end{document}`

Comment: If it should be an option: TeXing with LuaLaTeX (and a set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` or higher) works perfectly fine.

Comment: @StefanPinnow somehow the chart doesnt work.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Done.

Comment: No that still is not an MWE. You miss to load the `pgfplots` package and the `groupplots` library ...

Comment: ... and if you add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` before `\begin{document}` and compile with [tag:lualatex], then it works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code and must run in `LuaLaTeX` to get the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1},height=6cm,width=6cm,xmin=0.5,ymin=0.5,ymax=1,xmax=1,samples=500,ytick={0.5,1},xtick={0.5,1}, xlabel={$v_1$},
    axis lines=left]
        \nextgroupplot[title={}, ylabel={$x_1$}]
              \addplot[blue,]{min(1,(\x/(2*(1-min(1,\x)))))};\label{plots:plot1};   

              \addplot[black] {((3*\x-1)/(2*\x))};\label{plots:plot2};
                \addplot[black, dashed] {(\x)};\label{plots:plot3};
         \nextgroupplot[title={}, ylabel={$x_2$}]
              \addplot[blue]{(max((2-3*\x)/(2-2*\x),0))};\label{plots:plot1};        \addplot[black] {(1-\x)/(2*\x)};\label{plots:plot2};
                \addplot[black, dashed] {(1-\x)};\label{plots:plot3};
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- 
          node[anchor=south,rotate=90] { } 
          (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.south)--
      coordinate(legendpos) 
      (bot|-current bounding box.south);
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ]at([yshift=-1ex, xshift=-17ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plots:plot1}& F(x)&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot2}& G(x)&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot3}& H(x)& \\};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I said in the comments below the question, right!?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes, I agreed, I've collected your points, especially `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}`